# OpenVPN how to use multiple config files

Tags: openvpn, connection

Hi is there any way to change config files when I first time want to connect to one server and second time I want to connect to another server?

Or the only way is to create some .bat file to copy the right config files to folder every time I will need to change the destination server?

I think that the easiest way will be make .bat file with rm dir and xcopy new dir with right config files I want to at all.

If someone have a better idea so tell me.

Thank you for replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to rename ca.crt file and edit config file = you can insert more ca.crt files and .ovpn into one folder and then the application allows you to choose between .ovpn files where you want to connect.

Answer (score 0):

To do exactly what you describe you would need some kind of batch file. There are a few alternatives though -

1. You can have multiple config files and specify the one (or ones) you want to run using the `--config` option.  If you want to run multiple configs simultaneously you might need to specify different lport values in each depending on how good your NAT is.
2. You can have multiple "remote" options which the server will try in order that they appear (if you need redundancy)
3. If you can control DNS, you should be able to specify a subdomain with multiple A ( maybe even CNAME) records. If you specify this subdomain as the remote, it will randomly pick a host. If you do this you should run low TTLs to prevent a record being cached.

Answer (score -1):

I think that the easiest way will be make .bat file with rm dir and xcopy new dir with right config files I want to at all.

If someone have a better idea so tell me.

Comment: This is, jnfortunately not an answer to your question, so adding it as such is inappropriate. A nore appropriate way is to leave a comment or, as you may not have the rep, possibly edit your question.

Comment: I cannot delete this.